# android edit text value passed directly as parameter to object functions or constructors not working

Tags: android, android-edittext

Below is the class code:

```
public class UserInfo 
{
    String userName;
    String userPass;

    public UserInfo(){

    }
    public UserInfo(String userName, String userPass){
        userName=this.userName;
        userPass=this.userPass;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName){
        userName=this.userName;
    }
    public void setUserPass(String userPass){
         userPass=this.userPass;
    }
}
```

If I pass the string to object function from an activity as below : `userInfo.setUserName(et_login_user_name.getText().toString());`

Then userName is not set to the value of edit box. It is set to null.

But if I set the value as below:
`userInfo.userName=et_login_user_name.getText().toString();`

Then code works correctly.

Below is the activity class code:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    final Context ctx=this;

    final Button bt_login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    bt_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
            EditText et_login_user_name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
            EditText et_login_user_pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
//   userInfo.setUserName(et_login_user_name.getText().toString()); -not working 
//   userInfo.setUserPass(et_login_user_pass.getText().toString()); -not working

            userInfo.userName=et_login_user_name.getText().toString();  // working
            userInfo.userPass=et_login_user_pass.getText().toString();  // working
            if(userInfo.userPass.isEmpty()||userInfo.userName.isEmpty()) //get null pointer exception for non working code
            {
              //some code
            }
```

Comment: Have You tried to put some text in those EditText views? No characters in those is null, so maybe try put some strings in them firstly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning values incorrectly, instead of assigning value to class member you are assigning class member values to passed parameter. Ie instead of 
userName = this.userName use

this.userName = userName;

Answer (score 0):

Use this you are assigning value to local function variable from class variable . below code works for you now

```
public class UserInfo 
{
    String userName;
    String userPass;

    public UserInfo(){

    }
    public UserInfo(String userName, String userPass){
        userName=this.userName;
        userPass=this.userPass;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName){
        this.userName=userName;
    }
    public void setUserPass(String userPass){
         this.userPass=userPass;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.userName` points to the local variable `userName` of that class not the received parameters.

Initially these will be empty,

```
String userName;
String userPass;
```

Here is where you made the mistake.

```
 public void setUserName(String userName){
        userName=this.userName; // assume userName u passed was admin, then, admin = userName where userName is empty which causes null pointer exception
    }
```

So, it should be

```
public void setUserName(String userName){
        this.userName=userName; //in this case userName = admin;
    }
```

Also you need to change the same assigning things for entire thing in that class. So, your final code for the class should be

```
public class UserInfo 
{
    String userName;
    String userPass;

    public UserInfo(){

    }
    public UserInfo(String userName, String userPass){
        this.userName= userName;
        this.userPass =  userPass;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName){
        this.userName= userName;
    }
    public void setUserPass(String userPass){
        this.userPass =  userPass;
    }
}
```